# Как найти область матрицы

Tags: c, массивы

Какое условие должно быть, для того, чтобы пройтись лишь по левой стороне двумерного массива, как задано на фото?:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сообщите когда узнаете.

Comment: Подумайте, как будут соотноситься индексы по строке и по столбцу для данной области

Comment: всё зависит от координатной сетки, включительно или нет. Напишите свой пример, подскажем.